# Trying to limit the size of an image in an html table but it keeps resizing to fill the space

Tags: html, datatables

```
         <center>
  <a href="<?php echo $row['amazon_link'];?>"  target="_blank">  <img id="amz" src="<?php echo $row['image_link']; ?>" alt="" width="55px"> </a>
  </center>
```

I have the above code on this site here: http://audiobookreviews.com/1genre.php

But as you can see, the images keep trying to fill the screen even though I'd like it to max out at 55px.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try using this:

```
<img id="amz" src="qwerty.jpg" alt="" style="max-width: 55px;">
```

move width option inside style..

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you define your `width` inside Style tag.

```
style="max-width:55px"
```

or

```
style="width:55px"
```

both worked for me.

```
   <center>
       <a href="<?php echo $row['amazon_link'];?>"  target="_blank">  
           <img id="amz" src="<?php echo $row['image_link']; ?>" alt="" style="width:55px;"> 
       </a>
  </center>
```